# How can I change the index of input element dynamically based on parent and inner parent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, indexing

How can I change the index of input element dynamically based on the parent and inner parent count in jQuery.
In the following code how can I change the index of form elements

```
<div id='parent_container0'>
    <div id='parent_inner_container0'>
      <label> Name </label>
        <input type='text' name='name[]'/>
        <div id='child_container0'>
            <div id='child_inner_container0'>
                <label> Email </label>
                <input type='text' name='email[]'/>
                <label> Phone </label>
                <input type='text' name='phone[]'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='parent_container1'>
<div id='parent_inner_container1'>
    <label> Name </label>
    <input type='text' name='name[]'/>
    <div id='child_container1'>
        <div id='child_inner_container1'>
            <label> Email </label>
            <input type='text' name='email[]'/>
            <label> Phone </label>
            <input type='text' name='phone[]'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need the changed name of form element as

```
name[0]
email[0][0]
phone[0][0]
name[1]
email[1][0]
phone[1][0]
```

Based on the parent's index of those elements in jQuery.
How can I achieve this?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

**Note**: The requirement is to use a nested form to add more form of parent and Child with each form has nested form fields I am using the following code for changing index.

```
$('.parent_container').each(function(i) { 
    var pindex = $(this).index(); 
    var mainfrm=$(this); 
    var orgname=""; 
    mainfrm.find('.parent_container_inner').each(function(j) {  
        $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(k){ 
            orgname = $(this).attr('name'); 
            orgname = orgname.replace(/[[]\d]+/g,""); 
            $(this).attr('name', orgname+"["+pindex+"]["+j+"]["+k+"]"); 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Also curious why you need to do this

Comment: I am working with nested form clone. after submitting the form  I have to map child form values to parent child form values one byone

Comment: Don't really understand why mapping the data at server is any different than remapping names in client

Comment: Your requirement is very unclear. First of all, same question as @charlietfl, why do you need remapping names in the client? Second of all, do you want to consider the indexes on the id's like '1' in 'child_inner_container1' for remapping or are they irrelevant (as you put in your example)? Third and last, when you mentioned "form", are you refferring to this [form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should select your parent "containers" with:

```
$("div[id^=parent_container]").each(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

It will print your two `parent_container` (`parent_container0` and `parent_container1`). Check out here how to use selector attribute with [Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Then you will need to find and replace all `name[]`, `email[]` and `phone[]`.
So, you should use [Ends With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), to find each `input` you need to replace the `name`

```
$("div[id^=parent_container]").each(function(){
    var parentContainerId = this.id.replace('parent_container', '');
    $(this).find("input[name$='[]']").each(function(){
        var newName = this.name.replace('[]', '[' + parentContainerId + ']');
        this.name = newName;
    })
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpdxfq77/)

Also, concerning your question, you should definitely take a better look into [JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Note- Will work once but won't work if indexing needs to be done again such as removing a row

Comment: @charlietfl yes, but you can easily put it inside a function and call it when indexing needs to be done again.

Comment: point is selector would fail if you did that, will no longer have `[]` in name. May not be an issue depending on use case...just mentioning it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have n level of inner form like above form. I have to check every level and change the name of the form element based on those form element's level parent index. how can I achieve this.Can you give Any possible sample code  for common for all the inner forms.

Comment: @charlietfl true, even though you can change it for a more generic selector like `"input"`, and then replacing full name string instead of only "[]".

Comment: @sakthicrafty Ok. So I probably misunderstood it

Comment: Does this work without the brackets being balanced `$("div[id^=parent_container")` and does this work with the brackets being escaped `("input[name$='[]']")`?

Comment: @Popnoodles It did work, check the Fiddle. Don't know why. Fixed it.

Comment: @Popnoodles JQuery must balance automatically brackets in the latest versions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Note: The requirement is to use a nested form to add more form of parent and Child with each form has nested form fields I am using the following code for changing index.

Comment: $('.parent_container').each(function(i) {
      var pindex = $(this).index();
      var mainfrm=$(this);
      var orgname="";
      mainfrm.find('.parent_container_inner').each(function(j) {     
        $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(k){
      orgname = $(this).attr('name');
      orgname = orgname.replace(/[\[\]\d]+/g,"");
      $(this).attr('name', orgname+"["+pindex+"]["+j+"]["+k+"]");
      });      
      });      
     });

Comment: The above code work for two level. Need common code for all nested level fields. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @sakthicrafty It's better if you edit your question and add this information. Instead of commenting here.

Comment: @jmartins Thanks. Sorry. I am new to stackoverflow. I tried but I could not edit my questions.

Comment: Do you have another level of elements, below this level? `<div id="child_inner_container">`

Comment: Thanks @jmartins. yes. I have another level.